# What is Reflection in Java Can anyone explain?

Tags: reflection

Can anyone explain me this question that I have. 
What is reflection?
I tired find answer in here, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ability to inspect the code in the system and see object types is not reflection, but rather Type Introspection. Reflection is then the ability to make modifications at runtime by making use of introspection. The distinction is necessary here as some languages support introspection, but do not support reflection. One such example is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is the process of examining or modifying the runtime behavior of a class at runtime. It is used in:

• IDE (Integreted Development Environment) e.g. Eclipse, MyEclipse, NetBeans.

• Debugger

• Test Tools etc.